# odd numbers in language C? pb 'ram or algorithm'!

Tags: c, algorithm, ram

This program gives us the position of the odd numbers in a given integer, this program works well, but when I give him an integer in its numbers are greater than 10 -like 123456789123-, it doesn't work.
I do not know if is a problem of ram or algorithm ?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

main(){

    int a,b;
    int i = 0;

    scanf("%d",&a);

    while(a/10!=0){
        b=a%10;
        if(b%2!=0)
            printf("\nodd number position: %d",i);
        a=a/10;
        i++;
    }

    if(a%2!=0)
        printf("\nodd number position: %d",i);

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: if you're using C, why do you tag it as C++ as well?

Comment: “it doesn't work” So what does it do? Crash with an error message? Take forever? Provide the wrong answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is one of processor (architecture) rather than RAM. On your platform the size of an `int` seems to be 32 bits which cannot hold a number as large as 123456789123. As Groo commented to Raon, you could use a string instead (if you don't plan to do any calculations on the number):

```
char a[1024] = {0}; /* should be plenty, but extend the array even more if needed */

fgets(a, sizeof a, stdin); /* fgets is recommended as it doesn't overflow */

int i, length = strlen(a);

for(i = 0; i < length; i++){
    /* count your odd digits here
       left as an exercise to the reader */
    /* note that you must access the individual digits using a[i] */
}
```

Comment: okééy thanks, I think I understand so if I have a platform 64-bit the integer can be superior than 4294967295!!

Comment: Indeed, you can look at the macros in [`limits.h`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits) to see the minimum and maximum values of every type on your platform.

Comment: The macros are all numbers, so use the `printf("%d\n", INT_MAX);` form.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main() {

    int i;
    char s[256];

    scanf("%s",s);

    for( i=0; s[i]!=0; ++i ) {
        /*int digit = s[i]-48;
        if( digit%2==1 ) break;
        - or even shorter: */
        if( s[i]%2==1 ) break;
    }

    if( s[i]!=0 )
        printf( "First odd digit position: %d", i );
    else
        printf( "All digits are even" );
}
```

Here is working sample: http://cfiddle.net/sempyi

Comment: If you're going to rely on '0' being 48, you might as well not subtract 48 right? Subtracting an even number doesn't change the even-ness.

Answer (score 1):

Every data type is limited to specific range.for example `char` is limited to range `-128 to 128`. if you use the beyond this range. You might get unexpected results.

In your program if you give any number which is beyond the range of integer, then you will get unexpected results

if your int size is 4 byte/32-bit you can give input with in this range `–2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647`

if Your int size is 2 byte/16-bit you can give input with in this range `–32,768 to 32,767`

Check this [Data Type Ranges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

And if you want to give large Numbers You can declare variable as `long int/long long int` 
and don't forgot to change format specifier when using `long int(%ld)` and `long long int(%lld)`

You can also use string and check whether all characters are digits are not by using `isdigit()` function in `ctype.h` header and convert character digit into integer digit by substracting '0'`(character zero)`. and check whether is that odd or not.

Comment: thanks this answer help me to understand where the problem is

Answer (score 1):

The problem  is that 123456789123 exceed the storage limit for an integer data type,
try using a string to store the value and parse it, something like

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    char a[] = "12345678912345678913246798";
    int i = 0;
    for (i=0; a[i] != '\0'; i++){
        if ( a[i] % 2 != 0 ) printf("%c is odd\n", a[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: tanks it worke, i need just to change :
char a[] = "12345678912345678913246798"; with char a[]; gets(a);
and
printf("%c is odd\n", a[i]); with printf("%c is odd is position is %d\n", a[i], i);

Answer (score 0):

`123456789123` is `0x1CBE991A83`
so if int is 32 bit, your number is truncated (to `3197704835` or `0xBE991A83`).

Answer (score 0):

I think this program will not give proper answer if you give more than 10 digits! please correct me if I am wrong.
The max Unsigned integer value is 4294967295 (in any 32 bit processor). if the given value is more than that then it will either limit to that max value or overflow will happen. So if you give a integer which is more than 4294967295 it will not work as it supposed to.

try printing the input. In that case you will know whether complete number is sent or Max number is sent to find the odd number's position.

One way to make it work is read the input number as array of characters and then try to figure out the odd number position.

Note: for signed integer maximum is 2147483647

Answer (score 0):

Number you are giving input is greater than range of int. You need to change the data type Below link should help you.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ansi_c/c_basic_datatypes.htm

Answer (score 0):

You need to choose a data type that matches the expected data range.

If you want your program to work for any number it is probably best to read the number one character at a time.

Code (not that in this code, position is counted with the most significant digit = 1, which is the other direction compared to your code):

```
  int c;
  unsigned long long pos = 0;
  while (++pos) {
    c = getc();
    if (c < '0' || c > '9') break; // Not a digit
    if ((c - '0')%2 != 0) {
            printf("\nodd number position: %ulld", pos);
    }
  }
```

The code can handle numbers that have a ridiculus amount of digits. Eventually the `pos` variable will overflow, though.